# Had a confusion with dropdownlist

Tags: c#

Hi everyone one making an work hours. Which my boss wants me to create two dropdownlist one is hours of the day(1,2,3) and one is "00/15/30/45" . and radio button for AM PM. My problem is what is "00/15/30/45" means? What datetime format it is? O.o

-newbie junior programmer

Comment: My guess is that those are minutes.  Like a quarter hour, 15 minute intervals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should just ask your boss for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that those are minutes.  Like a quarter hour, 15 minute intervals.  Maybe the idea is that you can work 7 hours and 30 minutes, 6 hours and 45 minutes, etc.

[image]

You could ask him if you can just use decimals.  We used to use timetracker at work, and we'd just put in 7.5 for 7 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: So what should i put into that dropdownlist . im confused :(

Comment: You would put 00, 15, 30, 45 into the combobox.  It is for minutes.  But you should talk to your boss to clarify.

Comment: Thanks sir. I got it.

Comment: If my answer is the correct one you should update the accepted answer.  I don't know if the other answer is better?

Comment: Derek. Can you help? To understand my task. How can i compute my working hours in a week ,months,year if i only had "calendar ,two dropdownlist and radibuttonlist? Thanks

Comment: You really need to talk to your boss.  I don't know what he wants and neither do you.  You need to find out from him, it is much worse to just guess and end up doing something completely wrong.

Comment: I get the point of what i have asked. But this one seems to make me crazy
"Have the UI fetch this weeks' hours into a grid that sits above or below the controls for creating new
Have the total hours for the week, month and year displayed together nearby
Previously entered Hours are "read only".  WARN the users when they enter the data that it cannot be changed.
YES, it should be possible to create more than one entry per day for a user
The code should always check to see that the new entry start date is after the previous record end date"

Comment: It also might be a bad idea for him to make the things "read-only" - if he does that noone has a way to correct mistakes.

Comment: What i display in datagrid? The hours work for week ,months and year only? Is that what he wants. ? Thabks derek youre a big help

Comment: You really need to be asking your boss these questions.  Just look at the question you just asked me: "Is that what he wants. ? ".  You need to ask him.  Just to let you know, I am done with this question now, but I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, if the format is time (00/15/30/45) it may be hours/minutes/seconds/milli seconds... it means day started with 15 minutes and 30 secs and 45 milli secs  ... Like this (d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt)